# SSL Certificate Not Working for my Azure App Service

Tags: azure, ssl, https, azure-app-service-plans

I choose to host my website in Azure.So I've created a App Service.Then Created a new domain for my App then created/bind the [SSL certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site)  to my corresponding website.

After done with the SSL certificate .I'm still seeing my website url as **http//:** and not **https://**

Also i'm not seeing the Green URL for my Website ..!

It look like this

[image]

*(P.s : My App Service Tier is **AzureFreeTier (Basic: 1 Small)**

       My SSL Type is **SNL SSL**)*

Please help to resolve my problem here

Thanks in Advance,
Jayendran

Comment: So, what exactly happens when you point your browser to `https://yourdomain.com`?

Comment: You will not be redirected to https automatically from http if you install a cert, it just enables usage of https for your custom domain.

Comment: Yes when i tried with https://mydomain it also works.But i'm thinking it will always use https. And it's not like I've always need to change https: instead of http. Also i not getting the Green URL .Currently my https works in unsecure manner ( Says like **Your Connectuion to this site is not fully secure
Attackers might be able to see the images**)

Comment: @juunas Then how can i direct my portal to always use https:// Instead of http ?

Comment: Depends on your implementation framework. But basically you will need to redirect users to HTTPS. Adding strict transport security headers will then make sure it always happens later.

Comment: Is there any Configuration in the Portal Itself. So, that we can simply enable those option to "yes" to redirect always to https:// ?

Comment: @juunas After Login with the Active Directory Credentials I can able to see the https:// and also Secure Green URL link .But it not shown in the login page itself. Why is this behavior differ like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. Installing a certificate just makes using HTTPS with your custom domain name possible.

You can either:

1. Configure your app to redirect to HTTPS when it receives a request over HTTP + enable HTTP Strict Transport Security
2. Or use an extension in Web Apps to do the first thing:

To install the extension, open your web app blade in Azure Portal. Go to *Extensions*, then click *Add*. Then you should find *Redirect HTTP to HTTPS* from the list and install it.

[image: Extension list in the Web App]

That will redirect any HTTP calls to HTTPS for you. I would still recommend adding Strict-Transport-Security headers to your responses to make sure your clients do not access your site insecurely the next time.

The reason you arrive to your site on HTTPS after AAD login is because the HTTPS version of your app's URL has been configured in AAD as the reply URL.

And this:

> Your Connection to this site is not fully secure Attackers might be able to see the images

is a mixed content warning. It means you are loading content (e.g. images) using an HTTP URL in your pages. Change them to HTTPS and you will solve that problem.

Comment: After Adding the Extension i'm seeing a new config added under Web.config *<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://www.abcde.com/" />* Thnx. 
For Enabling the Strict -Transport-Security header i plan to use the this reference https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/01/07/https-only-on-windows-azure-web-sites/

But for your Answer regarding the replay URL AAD I couldn't catch it. How can i change the config to use my HTTPS before the AAD login (Login Page) ?

Comment: For the Mixed Content Warning i'm assume this will solve my probelm
https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2017/01/12/azure-app-service-force-redirect-from-http-to-https-the-easy-way/ ?
Or any other way to find what the contents are using HTTP ?

Comment: The addition to config did not come from the extension, I'm pretty sure of that. That is a standard setting added by Visual Studio templates. Before AAD, only your app can say that it should be over HTTPS. Enabling the extension should do that. I would recommend this article for HSTS: https://scotthelme.co.uk/hsts-the-missing-link-in-tls/. For fixing mixed content, easiest way is to open your browser dev tools with F12 and inspect what is loaded over plain HTTP.